# Numeric values in r and dealing with missing values

Tags: r

Using the example dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(
  KY27PHY1 = c("4", "5", "5", "4", "-", "4", "2","3", "5", "-", "4", "3", "3", "5", "5"),
  KY27PHY2 = c("4", "4","4", "4", "-", "5", "2", "3", "5", "-", "5", "3", "3", "5", "5"),
  KY27PHY3 = c("5", "4", "4", "4", "-", "5", "1", "4", "5","-", "4", "3", "3", "5", "5")),
                .Names = c("KY27PHY1", "KY27PHY2","KY27PHY3"),
                row.names = 197:211,
                class = "data.frame")
```

I have been using the following code to convert the values to numeric:

```
df$KY27PHY1<-as.numeric(df$KY27PHY1)
df$KY27PHY2<-as.numeric(df$KY27PHY2)
df$KY27PHY3<-as.numeric(df$KY27PHY3)
```

Since I have missing values in the df dataframe, I always get the warning message:

```
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

I presume this isn't a problem, but I just wanted some advice of how I might improve the code so I don't get this message.

Also, how I can do all the columns (specified by name) in one go?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: That's really helpful @flodel - I didn't know about that piece of code.

Comment: Well, I'll make it an answer then... If you would please accept one.

Answer (score 2):

I see two possibilities:

1. the unlikely one is that you built your data.frame in R. Then, just change your code to create integer vectors in the first place, or replace `-` with `NA` so the `as.numeric` conversion won't complain.
2. The more likely one is that your data.frame came from outside R and you probably read it with one of the `read.table` or `read.csv` functions. Then just add `na.strings = "-"` to your call and R will know that these `-` are to be understood as `NA`. Also, if there are no other weird items in these columns, the `type.convert` function called inside these functions will automatically detect that these are columns full of integers and store them as such.

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` is super fast, you should use it as soon as you work with `data.frames`. for your question that would be :

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(df)
dt[,lapply(.SD,as.numeric)]
    KY27PHY1 KY27PHY2 KY27PHY3
 1:        4        4        5
 2:        5        4        4
 3:        5        4        4
 4:        4        4        4
 5:       NA       NA       NA
 6:        4        5        5
 7:        2        2        1
 8:        3        3        4
 9:        5        5        5
10:       NA       NA       NA
11:        4        5        4
12:        3        3        3
13:        3        3        3
14:        5        5        5
15:        5        5        5
```

Off course you get some warnings as "-" cannot be converted to a number

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sapply` to do them all at once, but you will end up with a `matrix` so you have to wrap in an `as.data.frame` to convert back. The warnings are just there to tell you that there were characters in your original data that could not be matched to a number, so were replaced by `NA`. In your case these characters were `"-"`. To ensure the warnings do not print, use `suppressWarnings`:

```
suppressWarnings(as.data.frame(sapply(df,as.numeric)))
   KY27PHY1 KY27PHY2 KY27PHY3
1         4        4        5
2         5        4        4
3         5        4        4
4         4        4        4
5        NA       NA       NA
6         4        5        5
7         2        2        1
8         3        3        4
9         5        5        5
10       NA       NA       NA
11        4        5        4
12        3        3        3
13        3        3        3
14        5        5        5
15        5        5        5
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small function some time back to handle making certain values in a `data.frame` as `NA` and using `type.convert` to convert the output, as if you had used `read.table` with `na.strings` specified.

Here's the function:

```
makemeNA <- function(mydf, NAStrings, fixed = TRUE) {
  dfname <- deparse(substitute(mydf))
  if (!isTRUE(fixed)) {
    mydf <- data.frame(lapply(mydf, function(x) gsub(NAStrings, "", x)))
    NAStrings <- ""
  }
  mydf <- data.frame(lapply(mydf, function(x) type.convert(
    as.character(x), na.strings = NAStrings)))
  mydf
}
```

Here it is in use:

```
makemeNA(df, "-")
#    KY27PHY1 KY27PHY2 KY27PHY3
# 1         4        4        5
# 2         5        4        4
# 3         5        4        4
# 4         4        4        4
# 5        NA       NA       NA
# 6         4        5        5
# 7         2        2        1
# 8         3        3        4
# 9         5        5        5
# 10       NA       NA       NA
# 11        4        5        4
# 12        3        3        3
# 13        3        3        3
# 14        5        5        5
# 15        5        5        5
```

You can see from the `str`ucture that we now have numeric output.

```
str(makemeNA(df, "-"))
# 'data.frame':  15 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ KY27PHY1: int  4 5 5 4 NA 4 2 3 5 NA ...
#  $ KY27PHY2: int  4 4 4 4 NA 5 2 3 5 NA ...
#  $ KY27PHY3: int  5 4 4 4 NA 5 1 4 5 NA ...
```

As with `na.strings`, the `NAStrings` in `makemeNA` is *plural*. Here we make a dash and the values "1" into `NA`.

```
str(makemeNA(df, c("-", 1)))
# 'data.frame':  15 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ KY27PHY1: int  4 5 5 4 NA 4 2 3 5 NA ...
#  $ KY27PHY2: int  4 4 4 4 NA 5 2 3 5 NA ...
#  $ KY27PHY3: int  5 4 4 4 NA 5 NA 4 5 NA ...
```

---

You can also use regular expressions to set values as `NA`, as below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, "-", "not applicable", 5),
                 B = c("not available", 1, 2, 3, 4),
                 C = c("-", letters[1:4]))
```

Make any values with "not" or "-" into `NA`:

```
makemeNA(df1, "not.*|-", fixed = FALSE)
#    A  B    C
# 1  1 NA <NA>
# 2  2  1    a
# 3 NA  2    b
# 4 NA  3    c
# 5  5  4    d
str(makemeNA(df1, "not.*|-", fixed = FALSE))
# 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ A: int  1 2 NA NA 5
#  $ B: int  NA 1 2 3 4
#  $ C: Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c","d": NA 1 2 3 4
```